# How to get list of specific XML elements from XML document using C# ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xslt

I'm trying to get a specific bunch of elements from an XML document to be displayed using the XSLT file.

My code is successful, however, I don't know how to display specific elements based on a change in selection, rather than displaying the whole XML document.

My C# code:

```
string strXSLTFile = Server.MapPath("EmployeeXSLT.xslt");
string strXMLFile = Server.MapPath("Employess.xml");

XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(strXMLFile);

XslCompiledTransform objXSLTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
objXSLTransform.Load(strXSLTFile);

StringBuilder htmlOutput = new StringBuilder();
TextWriter htmlWriter = new StringWriter(htmlOutput);
objXSLTransform.Transform(reader, null, htmlWriter);
ltRss.Text = htmlOutput.ToString();
reader.Close();
```

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Employees>
  <Employee type="1">
    <ID>100</ID>
    <FirstName>Bala</FirstName>
    <LastName>Murugan</LastName>
    <Dept>Production Support</Dept>
  </Employee>
  <Employee type="2">
    <ID>101</ID>
    <FirstName>Peter</FirstName>
    <LastName>Laurence</LastName>
    <Dept>Development</Dept>
  </Employee>
  <Employee type="3">
    <ID>102</ID>
    <FirstName>Rick</FirstName>
    <LastName>Anderson</LastName>
    <Dept>Sales</Dept>
  </Employee>
  <Employee type="4">
    <ID>103</ID>
    <FirstName>Ramesh</FirstName>
    <LastName>Kumar</LastName>
    <Dept>HR</Dept>
  </Employee>
  <Employee type="5">
    <ID>104</ID>
    <FirstName>Katie</FirstName>
    <LastName>Yu</LastName>
    <Dept>Recruitment</Dept>
  </Employee>
  <Employee type="6">
    <ID>105</ID>
    <FirstName>Suresh</FirstName>
    <LastName>Babu</LastName>
    <Dept>Inventory</Dept>
  </Employee>
</Employees>
```

My XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//Employee">
      <div style="border:1px black solid;width:300px;margin:1px">
        <div>
          <b>Employee ID:</b>
          <xsl:value-of select="ID"/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <b>Name:</b>
          <xsl:value-of select="FirstName"/>
          <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="LastName"/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <b>Department:</b>
          <xsl:value-of select="Dept"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

HTML:

```
<asp:Literal ID="ltRss" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

Again, all I need with C# code is to select specific data based on user selection. Let's say a specific employee with "type = 3".

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Employees));
            Employees employees = (Employees)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

            Dictionary<int, Employee> dict = employees.employees
                .GroupBy(x => x.ID, y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

            Employee e100 = dict[100];
        }
    }
    public class Employees
    {
        [XmlElement("Employee")]
        public Employee[] employees { get; set; }
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        public int ID { get; set;}
        public string FirstName { get; set;}
        public string LastName { get; set;}
        public string Dept { get; set;}
    }
}
```